# Windows 7, ipconfig release and renew to change IP address

Tags: networking

I called my ISP to ask for a dynamic IP address, I did not realize I already had one by default.

So I asked if there was a way to renew my IP address with them, he informed me to open the command prompt and do `ipconfig release` and then `ipconfig renew`. But I have to figure this would only get a new IP from my router, and that my outside IP would still be the same.

Is there a way to change my IP outside of my LAN? (i.e. change the IP I see when I do a whatismyip?)

Comment: Go into your router, and change the WAN MAC address {using the [private ranges](http://serverfault.com/questions/40712/what-range-of-mac-addresses-can-i-safely-use-for-my-virtual-machines)}, then reboot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ipconfig release/renew` will refresh your local IP, not your public address. In many instances, simply restarting your router (a full power down *and* hit the reset button, not only the reset button) will have your home network query your ISP for a new dynamic address.

Comment: But this will only sometimes work I might think? Say I do it twice within 10 minutes (powerdown/up the router) will it just not give me a new one because it has not been long enough, or will it always give me the "freshest" IP?

Comment: It will vary ISP to ISP, as their rules/policies on assigning new dynamic addresses may be different. For example, provider A may instantly assign any newly-connected public device on their network a new address, while provider B may recognize the device as familiar and wait X amount of minutes before assigning another address.

Comment: You cannot force your ISP to get you a new IP address more then it wants to.  If you reset your modem you might get a new one but you will keep that assignment for a period of time

Comment: Your ISP will have a "IP Lease Time" and as commented above, they may assign new IP immediately, but usually they will see that your modem/router already have existing lease and the lease has not expired, and they will re-assign you the same IP. When your IP lease time has expired, then the ISP can decide to either re-assign you the same IP, or give you a new IP, and start the IP lease time again. (Which is Keltari's answer..)

Answer (score 0):

Zoredache's comment should work, assuming you can access your router's configuration.

Another possible method would be, assuming you can access your router's configuration, would be to look at the "DHCP Lease Expires" time (or something similar to that).  Turn your router off before that time and turn it on after.  You *may* be given a different IP.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that you usually get the same IP back unless you change the MAC
address first:

1. Click "Random"
2. Click "Update to value"
3. Restart modem

http://github.com/sietseringers/MACAddressTool